# How to check if keyboard button is getting spammed and add a cool down on before it can be pressed again

Tags: python, animation, timer, pygame, sleep

I want to know how to add a timer/cool-down to a specific key-button that is pressed. For example, the user is spamming the attack key (in my case p) and I want to add a cooldown to where the person cannot spam this button (in air and on ground).
Here is the problem:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XH-u-1qm2I0ftlCLPSsPMjTJjJGQdsUp/view?usp=sharing

As you can see in the video the person can spam the attack button indefinitely and removes the purpose of the game.

I have tried setting a sleep timer such as 
def sleeper():
    if input() == "p":
        s(20)
but I dont think that is how you do it.
Other than that I dont know any other methods to try.

Link to my entire code:
https://hastebin.com/zujanifisu.py

More specific code:

```
def movement(self, window):
        pygame.time.delay(20)
        if self.runcount >= 3:
            self.runcount = 0

        if self.running == True:
            window.blit(run[self.runcount],(int(self.player_x),int(self.player_y)))
            self.runcount +=1
            self.hitbox_running = pygame.Rect(self.player_x+30,self.player_y+20,48,70)
            pygame.draw.rect(window,(255,0,0),self.hitbox_running, 2)

        if (keys[pygame.K_DOWN]) or ((keys[pygame.K_DOWN]) and keys[pygame.K_p]):
            if self.player_y == 378:
                self.running = False
                if self.slidecount >= 4:
                    self.slidecount = 0

                if self.sliding:  
                    window.blit(slide[self.slidecount],(int(self.player_x),int(self.player_y)))
                    self.slidecount +=1
                    pygame.draw.rect(window,(255,0,0),self.hitbox_sliding, 2)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if (event.key == pygame.K_DOWN )and self.player_y < self.width:

                self.running = False
                self.jumping = False
                self.fallspeed += 0.2

                if self.fallingcount >= 1:
                    self.fallingcount = 0
                if self.fall:
                    window.blit(falling[self.fallingcount], (int(self.player_x),int(self.player_y)))
                    self.hitbox_falling = pygame.Rect(self.player_x+30,self.player_y,35,80)
                    pygame.draw.rect(window,(255,0,0),self.hitbox_falling, 2)                    
                    self.fallingcount +=1
        if keys[pygame.K_UP] and keys[pygame.K_p] :
            self.fallspeed = 0.3
            self.running = False
            self.jumping = False
            self.sliding = False
            if self.attackcount >= 16:
                self.attackcount = 0
            if self.attacking: 
                window.blit(attack[self.attackcount],(int(self.player_x),int(self.player_y)))
                self.attackcount += 1
                self.hitbox_attacking = pygame.Rect(self.player_x+30,self.player_y+20,38,70)
                self.hitbox_sword = pygame.Rect(self.player_x+72, self.player_y+20, 20, 50)
                pygame.draw.rect(window,(255,0,0),self.hitbox_attacking, 2)
                pygame.draw.rect(window,(255,0,0),self.hitbox_sword, 2)
            if self.jumpingcount >= 20:
                self.jumpingcount = 0
            if self.jumping and self.player_y < self.width:  
                window.blit(jump[self.jumpingcount],(int(self.player_x),int(self.player_y)))
                self.hitbox_jumping = pygame.Rect((self.player_x+20),(self.player_y+20),52,55)
                pygame.draw.rect(window,(255,0,0),self.hitbox_jumping, 2)
                self.jumpingcount +=1
                self.fallspeed = 0.3

        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.fallspeed = 0.3
            self.running = False
            if self.jumpingcount >= 20:
                self.jumpingcount = 0

            if self.jumping and self.player_y < self.width:  
                window.blit(jump[self.jumpingcount],(int(self.player_x),int(self.player_y)))
                self.hitbox_jumping = pygame.Rect((self.player_x+20),(self.player_y+20),52,55)
                pygame.draw.rect(window,(255,0,0),self.hitbox_jumping, 2)
                self.jumpingcount +=1
                self.fallspeed = 0.3

        if keys[pygame.K_p] and not keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.running = False
            self.jumping = False
            self.sliding = False
            if self.attackcount >= 16:
                self.attackcount = 0

            if self.attacking:
                self.hitbox_attacking = pygame.Rect(self.player_x+30,self.player_y+20,38,70)
                self.hitbox_sword = pygame.Rect(self.player_x+72, self.player_y+20, 20, 50)
                window.blit(attack[self.attackcount],(int(self.player_x),int(self.player_y)))
                self.attackcount += 1
                pygame.draw.rect(window,(255,0,0),self.hitbox_attacking, 2)
                pygame.draw.rect(window,(255,0,0),self.hitbox_sword, 2)
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.running = False


        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                self.running = True
                self.jumping = True
                self.fallspeed = 0.3

            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                self.running=True
            if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                self.running = True
                self.jumping = True
                self.sliding = True
```

Most of the problem is with the keys[pygame.k_p]

I want to add a timer to the overall button p, so when pressed like 2-3 times it cannot be pressed for another 2-3 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a key was pressed, then you've to store the time when the key is allowed to be "pressed" again.
Use Dictionary for that:

```py
key_timeout = {}
```

Write a function in global scope which checks if a key is pressed and allowed to be pressed. The parameters to the function are the state of the keys ([`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed)), the key and the time out time in milliseconds:

```py
def getPressed(keys, key, timeout):
```

If the key is not pressed the function returns `False`:

```py
if keys[key] == False:
    return False
```

Use [`pygame.time.get_ticks()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) to get the time in get the time in milliseconds:

```py
current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
```

If a timeout time is stored in the dictionary and and the time is less than the time when the key is allowed to be pressed again, then the function returns `False`:

```py
if key in key_timeout and key_timeout[key] > current_time:
   return Fase
```

Add the timeout time to the current time, this is the time when the key is allowed to be pressed again and store it to the dictionary.

```py
 key_timeout[key] = current_time + timeout
```

Full code of the function:

```py
key_timeout = {}
def getPressed(keys, key, timeout):
    global key_timeout

    if keys[key] == False:
        return False

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    if key in key_timeout and key_timeout[key] > current_time:
        return False

    key_timeout[key] = current_time + timeout
    return True
```

Instead of `if keys[pygame.k_p]:` you can call:

```py
if getPressed(keys, pygame.k_p, 2000): # 2000 milliseconds == 2 seconds
    # [...]
```

---

If you ask for the state of a key (e.g. `keys[pygame.k_p]`) multiple times in a function, then you've to store the result of `getPressed()` to a variable and use the variable instead. e.g.:

```py
key_p_pressed = getPressed(keys, pygame.k_p, 2000)

if (keys[pygame.K_DOWN]) or ((keys[pygame.K_DOWN]) and key_p_pressed ):
    # [...]

if keys[pygame.K_UP] and key_p_pressed:
    # [...]

if key_p_pressed and not keys[pygame.K_UP]:
    # [...]
```

Comment: I cant seem to implement it properply: paste.pythondiscord.com/axotoxijub.py and I tried moving the statement aronund but it wont work. Updated full pygame code with new things: paste.pythondiscord.com/jafutoneku.py

Comment: @WajdanFaheem `getPressed` is a function in global scope. When you use it, then  you just have to replace `keys[pygame.k_p]` by `getPressed(keys, pygame.k_p, 2000)` or store the result to a variable. Read the last part of the answer, which I've added right now.

Comment: For some reason it is not playing the animation and it doesn't set off of the cool-down. Just to be sure (sorry if I sound needy), for x amount of clicks, in y amount of time, z will be the wait time till it can be pressed again. That is the object of the question. Here is the implementation: [link](https://paste.pythondiscord.com/adobudiluy.py). Furthermore, just pygame.k_p does not work so I needed to add the keys()

Answer (score 0):

The term you're looking for is called "debouncing". As you've discovered, it's often useful to debounce user input to ensure that a single button isn't pressed too frequently, or so that a single long press isn't counted as multiple presses.

In any case, in order to debounce user input, you must keep track of the when the button was last pressed, and only make it eligible for another press once a sufficient amount of time has passed. Something like this should work:

```py
buttons_last_pressed = {}
...
now = time.time()
if is_pressed[BUTTON]:
    last_pressed = buttons_last_pressed.get(BUTTON)
    if (last_pressed is None) or (now - last_pressed >= threshold):
        buttons_last_pressed[BUTTON] = now
        do_the_thing()
```

You're right that you don't want to sleep, because sleeping blocks the rest of the game from making progress. Instead, just ignore future presses until a certain amount of time has passed.

Comment: I dont think I am implementing it correctly because its not really doing anything I was wondering if you can help me out? Here is a link to updated code: [link](https://paste.pythondiscord.com/ewaneyahem.py)

Comment: Also what is do the do_the_thing()? I do have that function or is it a general statement

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, `do_the_thing()` is just a placeholder for whatever logic you actually want to execute whenever the button is pressed.